# MySQL Can't Access root@localhost

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I'm facing this problem when trying to use MySQL in the command line. I'm using a Windows computer.

Below is my MySQL version details.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

Below is the command I'm running and the error I'm facing.

[Image of My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDVc5.png)

Comment: Please learn how to copy/paste content from the command window. Posting an image of your entire screen is simply not reasonable for people using mobile devices, and it's plain text content you couild very easily copy and paste directly into your question as text. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the issue, and that's not the case when it's plain text. If you're using Windows 7 or 10, you can even use the mouse to select the text, so it's extremely simple to do. Thanks.

Comment: You should also start with a simple search here for the exact error message, as this question has been asked (and answered) many times before.

Answer (score 0):

This post will save you a lot of time..
[Reset Forgotten MySql root Password Under Windows](https://jovicailic.org/2012/04/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password-under-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Your root user has a password. Use `-p` with the `mysql` executable if you know the password and you'll be prompted.

Otherwise the [mysql manual for 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) shows how to reset this password.

Blogs and Stackoverflow descriptions are frequently incorrect for the version that you using, particularly recently, because the mechanism has been changing between MySQL and MariaDB major versions. If in doubt, refer to the official documentation.